# Why is activity A started when activity B is destroyed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I got 2 activities, say A and B, A is started as usual through the launcher icon. B on the other hand is started through `BroadcastReceiver`. The thing I don't really understand here is when activity B is destroyed then activity A is opened?  I just can't see the connection in this, and this behavior is not wanted. I've solved this problem before by disabling history on activity A but new functionality enforces history to be used so another solution is needed for this.

Activity declaration in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.A" 
    android:noHistory="false" android:launchMode="singleTask"  
    android:label="@string/APP_NAME">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />   
    </intent-filter>
</activity>       
<activity android:name="com.example.B" android:noHistory="true" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/APP_NAME">
</activity>
```

And how activity B is launched from `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

I just don't really get how activity B finds it way to activity A after B is destroyed? How could this be prevented?

Comment: It's [activity's tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) that causes this. when activity B is launched, activity A will be stored in the back stack, when activity B is destroyed, activity A will be brought to foreground.

Comment: @li2, Okey, I understand that activity A must be stored in the backstack for this behaviour to occur, the thing I dont yet understand is how activity A is placed in the backstack? Since activity B is started from a receiver, which has nothing to to with activity A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch `B`, Android checks if there is already an existing task with the same `taskAffinity` as `B` (in your case, the task associated with `A`). If it finds one, it brings that task to the foreground and launches `B` on top of it. When `B` is finished, it drops the user into `A`.

To change this behaviour, you need to give `B` a different `taskAffinity` than `A`. Add this to the manifest declaration for `B`:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

Now `B` will be launched in its own task, even if there is already an existing task with `A` in it.

Be aware, however, that if `A` and `B` are running in separate tasks, you should probably provide a different icon, or at least a different label, for `B`, otherwise the user will be confused when he looks in the recent tasks list. He will see one entry for `A` and one entry for `B`, but they will both have the same icon and label.

Comment: @David Wasser, can you answer my question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427805/why-behaviours-are-different-androidlaunchmode-singletask-androidtaskaf